# how to export a function from one file to another node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some function that needs to be accessed from another file. But for some reason I can't do it.

```
 creatureScreenfunction (dir, jsonFile, pathToFile){
    let Mode = require('stat-mode'); 
    let temp; 
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) 
.............................................
   
}
```

Here's what I tried

```
exports.creatureScreen = creatureScreen();
```

in  second file

```
const index = require("../index.js");
```

Comment: You need to use module.exports and if they are in the same directory you will have to do `require('./'something.js)`

Answer (score 1):

What you did here `exports.creatureScreen = creatureScreen();` is named export. While importing it in some other file you need to do `const {creatureScreen} = require("../index.js");`.

Comment: exports.creatureScreen = creatureScreen();
give me error

Comment: You should assign the reference, rather than executing it at the time of the assignment. What I mean is replace `exports.creatureScreen = creatureScreen();` with `exports.creatureScreen = creatureScreen;`.